# Summing up all entered number in a textbox and display it in a disabled box

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I need to create a manual input counter using app script editor.

I've already have my website design with a single input textbox, reset button and a disabled box.

What I want is when I input a number in the textbox and press 'Enter' it will be displayed in the disabled box. If I repeat the process the new number in the textbox will sum up to the value inside the disabled box.

I would also like to have a reset button for the disabled box.

Lastly, having a record log of values inside the disabled box.

Is this even possible to make by just using HTML, JavaScript and AppScript?

Here's my code:

```
let box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
let box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
let historyContainer = document.getElementById("history");
let history = [];

//listen key enter press on the input
box1.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && e.target.value !== "") {
  box2.value = e.target.value;
  history.unshift(e.target.value);
  historyContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${e.target.value}</p>`;
  }
});
//reset the second box and
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box2.value = "";
});
```

I've used this code and what's happening is, when I input a number and press enter it displays in the disabled box (that's a good thing) however, the value in the textbox doesn't clear. Second things is, if I input a new number it doesn't sum up in the disabled box. Lastly, the history log records all values entered in the textbox and not in the previous value of the disabled box.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a demo for you as per your need. Please let me know if it fulfill your need.

To fix the problem faced by you, i am storing new value instead of previous value.

```js
let box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
let box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
let historyContainer = document.getElementById("history");
let history = [];

//listen key enter press on the input
box1.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && e.target.value !== "") {
  const summedValue = (box2.value && box2.value.trim() === "")  ? Number(box2.value) : Number(box2.value) + Number(e.target.value)
  box2.value = summedValue;
  historyContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${box2.value}</p>`;
  box1.value = "";
  }
});
//reset the second box and
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box2.value = "";
  historyContainer.innerHTML = ""
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="box1" />
<input type="number" id="box2" disabled />
<div id="history">
</div>

<button type="button" id="reset">
Reset
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! but as per his last ask, he wanted to show the previous value of disabled box not the value entered by the user.

Comment: I'll try puting this on my website and I'll let you know if this works. But anyways, thankyou so much for the help! :))

Comment: Hi Jasdeep Sing your code works! Thankyou so much. I would like to ask one last thing. Is it possible that all history logs will be stored in a spreadsheet? Cause when I tried it and accidentally refreshed the page all the history logs are gone :( is there a way that even if the page refresh the logs won't get deleted?